# selecting two columns that are named strangely

Tags: mysql

I have a `table` `schema` like this:

```
mysql> show columns from data;
+--------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field              | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ('Date', '')       | datetime | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ('Close', 'ABBV')  | double   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ('Close', 'ABMD')  | double   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ('Close', 'ABT')   | double   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ('High', 'ABBV')   | double   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ('High', 'ABMD')   | double   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ('High', 'ABT')    | double   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ('Low', 'ABBV')    | double   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ('Low', 'ABMD')    | double   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ('Low', 'ABT')     | double   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ('Open', 'ABBV')   | double   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ('Open', 'ABMD')   | double   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ('Open', 'ABT')    | double   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ('Volume', 'ABBV') | double   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ('Volume', 'ABMD') | bigint   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ('Volume', 'ABT')  | bigint   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ('Symbol', '')     | text     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
17 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If I say:

```
mysql> select DATE(`('Date', '')`) from data;
+----------------------+
| DATE(`('Date', '')`) |
+----------------------+
| 2010-08-10           |
| 2010-08-11           |
| 2010-08-12           |
| 2010-08-13           |
| 2010-08-16           |
...
```

It works. But, how do I ask for the data for `Text` or `Double`?

This doesn't work:

```
mysql> select DATE(`('Date', '')`), DOUBLE(`('Close', '')`) from data;
```

Neither does this:

```
mysql> select DATE(`('Date', '')`) DOUBLE(`('Close', 'ABBV')`) from data;
```

And this doesn't work:

```
mysql> select DATE(`('Date', '')`), DOUBLE(`('Close', 'ABBV')`) from data;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DOUBLE(`('Close', 'ABBV')`) from data' at line 1
```

Comment: Why are you calling conversion functions? The columns are already that type.

Comment: @Barmar, can you show what the query statement should be?

Comment: See [Cast functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html) for datatype conversion functions in MySQL.

Comment: @Ivan just ``select `('Close', '')` from data;``; the DATE function isn't doing anything to help find your datetime field (though it is removing the time component)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to call a conversion function, since the columns are already declared to be that type.

You can use aliases in the query to give simpler names to the columns when selecting.

```
select `('Date', '')` AS date, `('Close', '')` AS close from data;
```

Comment: how do I get  a date? Doesn't work: mysql> select `('Date', '')` AS date, `('Close', 'ABBV')` AS close from data where date > '2021-01-01';

Comment: You can't use aliases in `WHERE`, you have to use the real column name ```WHERE `('Date', '')` > '2021-01-01'```

Answer (score 2):

My best advice is to create a new table and insert the data:

```
create table data2 (
    date datetime,
    close_abbv double,
    . . .  -- repeat for all the columns
);

insert into data2
    select *
    from data;
```

Comment: Yes, I have been thinking that each symbol should get it's own table

Comment: @Ivan . . . I don't know what you are really trying to do.  This is a suggestion so you have a reasonable table to work with.

Comment: No, each symbol should definitely not have its own table, but rather be stored on a different row, one row per date/symbol, with columns date, symbol, close, high, low, volume.  (Not sure what your text column is for)